# time-freeze-effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I want to make a freeze time effect (also known as a bullet-time effect) in blender. so the camera is moving, but everything in the frame stands still. I already have a smoke simulation and I want to pause it on one frame. while the smoke simulation is paused the camera should move around the smoke. Does anyone have an idea how doing that? Thank you for your answer. (I am in cycles)

Answer (score 1):

Just set your simulation to end at the frame you want everything to freeze, you can move your camera and the smoke will be frozen.

Here you can see where you can set the end of the simulation:

[image: Smoke simulation]

To freeze the rest of the objects you can do what the other answer said.

Comment: where can I set it to end ?

Comment: probably he wants to _animate_ the camera,not move it in the viewport...I guess this won't work...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this.

Use key frames - set key frames for your main objects up to the point that you want to transition into "bullet-time". At the point, have no more animation/key frames for these objects.

However, continue the animation, setting the keyframes for the camera. Assuming that the camera was not moving in the first place, your first camera keyframe would be when everything else stops moving. You can then move and rotate your camera around the scene. IF the camera is moving in the first place - still move and rotate.

Comment: How can I set these keyframes for the smoke? My main object is the smoke and nothing else is moving. I am not working with smoke so often so I am sorry for the bad understanding. :/